# multiplying rows in gridview without page refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview for my web application in which there is quantity and unit price column and total column. If I type quantity and unit price then I want to display the total price automatically in next column. But for my current coding it will display only after the page reload by I clicking on the add button only. I need to display the total amount automatically when I move to the Total column. This is my current code.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txttotal" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Qty")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Uprice"))%>' 
        AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>`
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the code instead of putting it in comments. It is a lot easier to read in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke a javascript function from gridview rowdatabound like below:

```
 txtFATObj.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "Calculate('" + txtFATObj.ClientID + "','" + txtSNFObj.ClientID + "','" + txtNETWTObj.ClientID + "','" + txtTSObj.ClientID + "')");
```

**Calculate()** is defined on the aspx page or in a separate JS file.You can now calculate based on these parameters received and set the value.

Define RowDataBound like this where you need to find your controls and send the captured values to javascript.**Actual calculation will occur at javascript end.**

```
protected void grvCalc_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox txtFATObj = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtFAT");
            TextBox txtSNFObj = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtSNF");
            TextBox txtNETWTObj = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtNETWT");
            TextBox txtTSObj = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtTS");

            txtFATObj.Attributes.Add("onfocusout", "Calculate('" + txtFATObj.ClientID + "','" + txtSNFObj.ClientID + "','" + txtNETWTObj.ClientID + "','" + txtTSObj .ClientID + "')");

        }
    }
```

Comment: sir how to add the calculate function in java